# How do I use my .pem file from Amazon EC2 with mosh?

Tags: networking, ssh

To login with `ssh` I do this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/kp1.pem ubuntu@ec2-xxxx.com
```

I tried all this with `mosh`:

```
mosh --ssh='ssh -i ~/.ssh/kp1.pem ubuntu@ec2-xxxx.com'

mosh -i ~/.ssh/kp1.pem ubuntu@ec2-xxxx.com
```

But I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/mosh: could not get canonical name for /home/$USER/.ssh/kp1.pem: Name or service not known
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
/usr/bin/mosh: Did not find remote IP address (is SSH ProxyCommand disabled?).
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up needing to run the command like this:

```
mosh --ssh="ssh -i ~/.ssh/kp1.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xxxx.com
```

This works, but I also needed to add a rule for port `60001` for `mosh` to run on in the EC2 management console under security groups.